# How to select multiple items in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an enum with cases.  I am trying to make a multiple item selection UI so I can select the cases in my enum.  Please see my desired result below.  I then want to get back what items the user has selected.

I was thinking a HGrid and a button for each case in my enum.  The only problem is how would I get back what values of the enum the user pressed?

How would I be able to accomplish something like the below picture?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: It's a very vague question. Which part exactly are you having a problem? Please be more specific on the part where you really are struggling.

Comment: Would you show your code for this?

Comment: Have a var selected as part of each of your data that the displayed views are pulling their data from, and display one  way for selected, and another for not selected. Add a tap gesture to the views and toggle selected whenever it is tapped.